# create profile URL like in Facebook OR Subdomain

Tags: facebook, url, subdomain, profile, cpanel

Is that a subdomain in facebook profile or it is just a url that shows specific profile based on name followed after e.g. `www.facebook.com/profile-name`
If it is just a profile URL then I want to do like so in my website for each user to be able to have their own profile url like facebook.

I want to do this by php script when any user registers for my site it should be created then.
thanks.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The way you do that sort of thing is using `apache mod_rewrite` this way you simply make rules for how apache translates incomming requests and what php file will respond.

[apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: can you please explain in detail.. as how to make it work.. ??